# View Database Connector Module not working

Tags: views, 8

I am using the [Views Database Connector](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_database_connector) module in drupal 8 to display the data from external database.

I have also set the both database setting in setting.php, but still I am unable to see the VDC in view. can anybody please let me know how can I do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Since this module was released Jan 2015, I highly doubt that it is still compatible with the current Drupal 8. A lot changed since then. Looks like you need to apply a patch. See [Not compatible with latest Drupal 8 RC](https://www.drupal.org/node/2610480), but from reading the comments, apparently this patch is not compatible with the latest Drupal 8.0.1 Therefore, looks like you'll have to wait until the maintainer or a community member provides a new patch.

Comment: Is there any other way so that i can get external database and show it in view ?

Comment: @Gaurav sorry I don't know any other way for D8.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report for a contributed module. We can't help with bug reports here, please open/follow an issue in the project queue on Drupal.org. Thanks

Comment: @Guarav apparently the patch works after all... https://www.drupal.org/node/2610480